# Cell validation - checking if date [Excel VBA]

Tags: vba, excel

I have some code that is running on the background. Part of it, I would like to check if cells in Col13 (sheet = 'Project_Name') have values that are in date format. If not, I would like to notify the users.

Col13 will be a date if flagged cells in Admin sheet are marked as 'True' - just so you know understand what is first part of my code is for.

**CODE**

```
'Checking date of activity
For i = 7 To LastRow
    With Worksheets("Admin")
        If .Cells(i, 13).Value = "True" Or .Cells(i, 11).Value = "True" Then
            With Worksheets("Project_Name")
                If Not IsDate(.Cells(i, 13)) Then
                    MsgBox ("Please ensure that Date of Activity is in the correct Date format.")
                    Exit Function
                End If
            End With
        End If
    End With
Next i
```

Albeit a very simple loop check, it does not work. I am not sure if my statement:

```
If Not IsDate()
```

is correct?

Any advise would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks right to me. Can you expand on why it is not doing what you expect?

Comment: If I use a value, say "x" in cell where it is supposed to be a date, it does not pick it up..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If columns K and M on the Admin worksheet contain truly boolean values (center aligned TRUE or FALSE on the worksheet) then you shouldn't be comparing them to strings that look like `"True"`. Their underlying raw boolean value is sufficient to evaluate.

```
If .Cells(i, 13).Value Or .Cells(i, 11).Value Then
    ...
end if
```

Comment: Are you stepping through with F8 and can actually see it reach the IsDate? If the above applies to your situation, IsDate may never be reached.